# Serve static content and views from same directory?

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

Is it possible to serve static content and views from the same directory? 
I found a partial solution below:

```
//Enable Express static content serving:  
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/html')); //Static path is folder called html

//Also enable EJS template engine: 
app.engine('.html', require('ejs').__express);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/html'); //Set views path to that same html folder
app.set('view engine', 'html'); //Instead of .ejs, look for .html extension

//Start server
app.listen(8000);

//Express routes: 
app.get('/', function(req,res) {
    res.render('index', { message: 'hello world'});   
    //this only serves static index.html :(
}); 

app.get('/home', function(req,res) {
    res.render('index', { message: 'hello world'}); //<-- this serves EJS
    //whoo-hoo! serves index.html with rendered EJS 'hello world' message
});
```

This is working perfectly, except for the first route '/' which does not render EJS.   All other routes (/home, /about, etc) will conveniently serve the dynamic EJS along with static content.  Is there anyway to trick that first '/' to work in the same way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Express 3.x try putting router before static:

```
 app.use(app.router);
 app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'html')));
```

For Express 4.x the router has been deprecated but the concept is the same as routes are like middleware so you should be able to call them before the static middleware.

Comment: It seems that `app.router` has been deprecated, and this no longer works.

Comment: @cgmb - thanks - Ive made a note in post. The process should be the same I would assume since it's all first come first use middleware.