# Serving a mix of static and dynamic content with node.js & express

Tags: node.js, dynamic, express, static

This is similar to entry [21105801](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21105801/serve-static-content-and-views-from-same-directory), but not quite.

(Versions: express@4.7.2, node@0.10.29)

I'm trying to create one route that will serve either a dynamic page if it is found or pass to a static router (via next()) if not.

My route should operate like this, app.get('/' -> authenticate -> try to serve dynamic -> try to serve static.

I've added an authorize route that handles Oauth 1 & 2, and everything was working fine with just static pages. But I would like to serve customized pages after authentication and there are three problems I've encoutered.

1. I don't want to explicitly serve every dynamic page by name using 'render()' so I build the filepath by hand and bypass the 'view' logic. This works for the HTML, but...
2. it doesn't work for the JS and CSS that I use for my Foundations. In fact, render() never calls the callback with an error because it can't find the css/js files, it even thinks the path is a module?
3. Seems odd that the view engine requires everything to be in one view path. Or am I missing an obvious design pattern?

Here is the route:

```
app.use(
    "/", // i like being pedantic
    authorize, // pass through the auth filter
    function(req, res, next) { // try to serve dynamic page
        // build the filename
        var file = __dirname + '/restricted' + req.url;
        console.log("Rendering file "  + file);
        res.render(file, { username: req.user.username } , function(err, html) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("ERROR: " + err);
                next(); // pass to static router
            } else {
                res.send(html); // or send the page
            }
        })
    },
    // fallthrough route for js/css statics
    express.static(__dirname + "/restricted")
);
```

Here's the error, it is trying to read index.html which calls a CSS template and JS rel.

```
GET /auth/twitter/callback?oauth_token=... 302 329.979 ms - 78
Rendering file /home/pt/www/restricted/index.html
ERROR: null
       ^---- this worked!
GET /index.html 200 7.097 ms - 838
Rendering file /home/pt/www/restricted/css/foundation.css
               ^---- that's the file I want to read!
GET /css/foundation.css 500 9.846 ms - 871
    ^---- keep going!!!
Error: Cannot find module 'css'
                   ^---- DOH! Why does it look for a module?!?!? Why no error callback?
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

Thanks in advance.

I think I'm trying to do something really obvious but just about all of the dynamic view engine examples call res.render('filename') for each explicit file which seems absurd: why change your router code every time you add a new dynamic page?

Comment: Are you sure you can pass multiple functions to app.use() like that? Their website is down for me right now so I'm looking at these docs: https://web.archive.org/web/20140706041538/http://expressjs.com/api

Comment: @mshindal : No, that's not the issue here. He can use as many functions in `app.use()` as he wants.

@PeterT, do you really need to try serving dynamic content *before* your static content ? Usually people do this the other way around.

Comment: Hi @WaldoJeffers: no, I don't need to serve static before dynamic, but if I swap the rules above, won't the static router serve the template version of index.html before the dynamic parser renders it? (I could separate my static and dynamic content but they all use the same js/css subdirs and it feels weird to store more than one copy.)

Comment: Well, if you have an `index.html` in your static folder, the router will obviously serve it, but isn't that the point ? 
I mean, usually your **static** files (.css,.js, img etc...) are stored in a `/public` directory (which does not require authentication), and the app works in the following way : -> try to match a static file -> try using the router's routes -> 404. 
And Express allows you to specify a `views folder`  by doing `app.set("views", __dirname + "/views")` which saves you the trouble of creating a path for each file you want to render.

Comment: Usually, an app looks like :
`app.use("/public", modules.express.static('./public'));`
`app.get("/index, function(req,res){ res.render("index.jade"); });`
`app.get("/faq", function(req,res){ res.render("faq.jade");});`

Comment: if I switch the rendering engine to use EJS files, and write a GET route for '/*.ejs' it seems to work (again, I'm trying to avoid an explicit route for each EJS template). Your idea of serving static pages for the default '/' -BEFORE- serving templates made me think of using regex in the GET to only handle templates. Thanks for that prod, as it now works (and even handles subdirs with EJS just fine).

Comment: One more question for you, @WaldoJeffers, is serving templates using app.get('/*.jade', ...) frowned upon? I'm suspicious of explicitly coding routes to actual dynamic pages (e.g., app.get('/index'), etc.). Doesn't this mean the router has to be edited for each new dynamic page? Or is that the point? Thanks again.

Comment: I don't know if it's "frowned upon", but it's definitely not the usual way. Indeed, the apps usually have a fixed amount of endpoints (meaning you edit the router each time). If you really to want to create dynamic routes, I suggest you to do something like :
`app.get("/dynamic/:page",function(req,res){ res.render(req.params["page"] + ".jade"); });`

Answer (score 2):

- Use global wilcard route[ app.use('/') ] for static content and
- Use specific routes [ app.get(/myroute), app.post('/anotherroute')] for dynamic processing using custom logic

```
//Serves resources from public folder 
app.use('/',express.static(__dirname + '/public')); 

//Verify the complete directory path - especially slashes 
console.log('Static directory '+__dirname + '/public');

//serve on custom routes
app.get('/list', function (req, res) {
    res.send('<html><body><h1>Hello World</h1></body></html>'); });
```